# How to display time amount to user?

Tags: java, time

I want to convert time amount from milli-sec to a human readable string.

For example:

`3,600,000` should be displayed as `1:00:00` (1 hour).

Is there an existing library or class in Java that can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 1.5 there is the java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit class, use it like this:

```
String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
);
```

For Versions below 1.5 You have to use

```
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```

Comment: Add zero checking for the below 1.5 version code.But using java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit class there is no need indeed.

Comment: I think I didn't understand. In your first example, if minutes are 0, I don't want to display them. is there a formater that will do that?

Comment: Well According to your requirement you need the second solution with zero checking.The first one will format and print min and sec value even when the value is zero.Like 1:00:00 . But you said you don't need them

Comment: First one is a String Formatter Where java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit class is used to convert millis